# Updating data that is passed into child component Angular2

Tags: meteor, angular, components, angular-meteor

I am new to development in Angular2 - Meteor. I have stumbled upon a problem while working with parent-child components. In the parent component, I have meteor subscribing to a collection.

```
users: any;

constructor(private _zone:NgZone){


    var sub =  Meteor.subscribe("accounts/users");
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
        _zone.run(function() {
            if(sub.ready()){
                this.users = Meteor.users.find().fetch();
                console.log(this.users);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

The user collection has 90 users in total. When the app initially loads, only the current user is found, thus the console log shows one user.

I am not sure if my placement of Tracker.autorun() and NgZone are correct, but after a second of the app loading, the console log shows an array of all 90 users. I assume this happens because the subscribe is not ready at first.

My child component takes in the fetched users as a parameter like this `<sd-table [data]="users"></sd-table>`. Upon loading of the application, there is only one user that is seen on the drawn template of the child component. Is there any way that the template can be updated when the subscribe happens and all users become accessible?

Comment: Did you try using the meteor component methods?

Comment: I don't think so, are you talking about this? [link](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/meteor-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to `this` of the current class, don't use `function()`

```
users: any;

constructor(private _zone:NgZone){
    var sub =  Meteor.subscribe("accounts/users");
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        _zone.run(() => {
            if(sub.ready()){
                this.users = Meteor.users.find().fetch();
                console.log(this.users);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me, I am using ngOnChanges in my child component and it finally identifies that the data changes. But this happens after the template is loaded, is there a way to make the template update when the component receives the new data?

Comment: There is no specific feature, just add `*ngIf="users"` to the outermost element of your template when you want the component to render only after `user` is set.